# Trying to filter datetime fields based on time only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, squeel

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to build a scope for a specific type of query I'm trying to do.

Basically I have an Availabilities model which has a `start_time` and `end_time` datetime columns.

I have a start and end time dropdown in my view which returns this query on search:

```
 "availabilities"."start_time" >= '2015-10-27 00:00:00.000000' AND "availabilities"."end_time" <= '2015-10-31 00:00:00.000000'
```

I've been asked to add a new time range filter:

```
Morning (6am - 12pm)
Afternoon (12-6pm)
Night (6pm - 12am )
```

I'm not sure how I'd approach that. This is what an availability record looks like:

```
   <Availability:0x000000065b2bf0> {
                 :id => 1,
         :start_time => Sat, 21 Nov 2015 11:00:00 UTC +00:00,
           :end_time => Sat, 21 Nov 2015 12:00:00 UTC +00:00,
              :price => 24.1,
           :discount => 20.0,
         :created_at => Fri, 23 Oct 2015 21:31:49 UTC +00:00,
         :updated_at => Fri, 23 Oct 2015 21:31:49 UTC +00:00,
        :facility_id => 1,
         :booking_id => nil
    }
```

So I need to filter only on the time portion of the field but am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use a part of a timestamp in a query depends somewhat on what database you're using.  For example, with PostgreSQL you could use the extract function to group or filter things based on the time of day.

If you're unsure how to do that, you could also look at the groupdate gem (https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) which appears to do what you're looking for in a more database agnostic way.

Comment: An example rails .where using the postgres extract could be .where("extract(hour from start_time) in (6,7,8,9,10,11,12)") for the 6am-12pm time slot.

Comment: The above code really helps actually. The gem not so much since I can't really do anything with the grouped data as far as I can see. It works well for charts which ill be using in the future but to record records with the time range I don't see how I'd use the gem here.

Comment: I just realized this isn't going to work. Timezones are going to be an issue. Is it at all possible to apply a timezone to the column before checking against it?

Comment: Yep, Postgres can do time zones.  If your data is stored as a "timestamp with time zone", you can request that it be manipulated in any time zone you care for with the suffix "at time zone 'ZZZ'" after the column name (where ZZZ is the zone code), or if it's stored as just a timestamp, you can use the same suffix in interpret it as the time zone it's stored in, and then use the suffix again to convert it to a different time zone.  I recommend reading the date/time type & functions sections of the postgres documentation; their documentation on those items is very good.